# Is there any way to generate the deps list for particular rules?

Tags: dependencies, bazel, bazel-extra-action

I have a program that can look at my language's source file, and derive the correct value for the `deps=[]` value of its build rule.

I'm looking for a way to replace all my existing rules (that look like this):

```
build_lib(name = "foo", deps = [...])
build_lib(name = "bar", deps = [...])
build_lib(name = "baz", deps = [...])
```

To instead be:

```
build_lib_new(name = "foo")
build_lib_new(name = "bar")
build_lib_new(name = "baz")
```

with the same specified deps resolved internally in the rule by calling my program.

Ideally, `build_lib_new` would just be a wrapper rule around `build_lib`:

```
def derive_deps(name):
    deps = []
    # call my tool somehow?
    return deps

def build_lib_new(name):
    deps = derive_deps(name)
    build_lib(name,deps)
```

Now I'm stuck.  Unfortunately, I think bazel wants to know all the dependencies up front as part of the analysis phase.  I see that their are actions to run shell commands, but I believe those happen after the dependency graph is made.

Do I have to run the external tool outside of bazel to rewrite `BUILD` files?

Comment: If you want to write such a tool, look at https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools. It contains functions useful for parsing / editing / printing a BUILD file. We'll extend the features overtime to make easier to build this kind of tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have to run the external tool outside of bazel to rewrite BUILD files?

In short, yes. This is why tools like Gazelle and Jadep exist.

If your tool runs as actions *during* execution phase, then the deps would be non-existent during loading and analysis phase. You'll need to run the tool *before* loading/analysis, maybe as a [repository rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/repository_rules.html)?

> I see that their are actions to run shell commands, but I believe those happen after the dependency graph is made.

Correct. The analysis phase creates the configured target graph, and reifies it into the action (shell commands, artifacts, etc) graph for the execution phase.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation.  Gazelle, Jadep, and repository rules sound promising.